# Jquery ajax post is not working with cakephp framework but it is working with core php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am Trying to do pagination inside the modal window.Modal window is working fine.Doing pagination using jquery.here Bootpag is working fine but data is not posting to the specified url.

index.ctp

```
<!--/to display the modal window-->
    <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('table_name', array('hiddenField' => true, 'value'=> $_GET['table_name'],'id'=>'table_name'));?>

                              <div id="results"></div>
                              <div class="pagination"></div>


    <!--/to display the pagination-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#view_model").click(function(){
           var table=$('#table_name').val();
         $(".pagination").bootpag({
                 total: <?php echo $pages; ?>,
                 page: 1,
                 maxVisible: 5
            }).on('page', function(e, num){
               e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
           url:+"/FetchPages/index",
           data:{'page':num,'table':table},
           type:"POST",
           success:function(response)
           {
               $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="/phygital_visualize/loaderIcon.gif" /> Loading...</div>');
              console.log(response.status);
           }

         });
        });
      });
     });
    </script>
```

FetchPagesController.php

```
<?php

class FetchPagesController extends AppController {
  public function index(){

    //$table_name = $_GET['table_name'];
    $table_name = $this->request->data('table');

    App::import('Model', 'ConnectionManager');
    $con = new ConnectionManager;
    $cn = $con->getDataSource('default');

    $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM $table_name";
    $results = $cn->query($sql1) ;

    $item_per_page = 10;
    //$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_row($results); //total records
    //break total records into pages
    $pages = ceil($results[0][0]['count']/$item_per_page);
    $this->set('pages',$pages);

    //sanitize post value
     $page = $this->request->data('page');
if(isset($page)){
        $page_number = filter_var($page, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
        if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
    }else{
        $page_number = 1;
    }
    $position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
?>
```

Comment: You created a mess with core php and cakephp. Try to post value to `/FetchPages/index` using postman and check if you are getting the desired output from the page. You can check the error on the console of browser. If you get that share with us.

Comment: Use `$this->request->data('page');` instead of `$_POST["page"]`

Comment: I have did that change what you have suggested.Then also in the response status jquery is returning undefined for the line .on('page', function(e, num){

Comment: can you confirm the url on which ajax is being hit.

Comment: Also **_NEVER EVER_** insert (user)data into queries directly, **_ALWAYS_** use prepared statements when using custom SQL! What you have there is an SQL injection vulnerability!

Comment: Real quick, in your AJAX config object, you have `url:+"/FetchPages/index"`. Is the plus sign (`+`) a typo, or do you actually have that in your code? Because `+"/FetchPages/index"` evaluates to `NaN`.